# the image boxes have different sizes(width)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
}

.image-part {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.image-part h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.image-part p {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-part">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/blue-grape-hyacinths.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>bluefruit</h3>
      <p>spring is amazing</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-part">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sakura-trees.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>pink</h3>
      <p>tree</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-part">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/blue-grape-hyacinths.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>anotherpicture</h3>
      <p>blue is my favorite</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-part">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sakura-trees.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>beautifultree</h3>
      <p>pink ia </p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-part">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/blue-grape-hyacinths.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>pic</h3>
      <p>pic</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a container and some content (image and text) in it (also every image is in a container). the container has `display: flex;` and the flex items have `flex-basis: 20%;`. I  want the items to have the same width but they appear differently.

I think it is becuase of the text in the items. I used `h3` and `p` tag.

can someone help me with this?
[this is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/tcomw5p0/)

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question, no need for an external link with such a simple html/css setup.

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden;` on .image-part

Comment: I tried `overflow: hidden;` and it worked. but I'm confused. how it worked? because the content of the `h3` and `p` tag weren't out of the box. @DavidHänni

Comment: like this ? @0stone0

Comment: `min-width: 0` to image-part